# What is the Pythonic way of using a moving x,y coordinate dataclass as a dict key?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class coordinate:
    x: int
    y: int

objects = {}

pos = coordinate(0, 0)

objects[pos] = "A"

pos.x += 1 # Changing the current position I am looking at

objects[pos] = "B"

pos.y += 1

objects[pos] = "C"

for position in objects:
    print(position, objects[position])
```

This throws `TypeError: unhashable type: 'coordinate'`.

Setting `@dataclass(frozen=True, eq=True)` throws `dataclasses.FrozenInstanceError: cannot assign to field 'x'`.

And finally, using `@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)` results in:

```
coordinate(x=1, y=1) C
coordinate(x=1, y=1) C
coordinate(x=1, y=1) C
```

One way way to do this is to use `objects[(pos.x, pos.y)]`, but that just seems to defeat the purpose of using the dataclass in the first place. Is there a *better*, more pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: If you don't actually need a `dataclass`, a `complex` number might work for you. You can do `pos += 1` and `pos += 1j` with that.

Comment: @KellyBundy had no idea whatsoever that complex numbers were a thing in python, so I've learned something entirely new today!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dict` keys should be immutable objects, so `frozen=True` is non-negotiable.

To "modify" a frozen object, you need to make a copy of it. The `dataclasses` module provides a convenience function for that, `replace`.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, replace

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class coordinate:
    x: int
    y: int

objects = {}

pos = coordinate(0, 0)

objects[pos] = "A"

pos = replace(pos, x=pos.x+1) # Changing the current position I am looking at

objects[pos] = "B"

pos = replace(pos, y=pos.y+1) 

objects[pos] = "C"

for position in objects:
    print(position, objects[position])
```